# What was the emergency referring to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Tokyo entered **a state of emergency** on July 12 amid concerns that an influx of tens of thousands of athletes and officials during the July 23--August 8 Games will spread the corona virus, cases of which are already rising in the Japanese capital.

Did **emergency** referred to the emergency caused by people's concerns or the epidemic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"State of emergency" is an idiom.  It means a situation (or state) in which the government takes extra powers to deal with some problem or remain in control.

The emergency was the potential for visitors to the Olympics to spread covid19, and the consequences of that.

Comment: Thank you very much!